# Wrap NSString stringWithFormat: across multiple lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am wrapping my SQL statement for FMDatabase in a NSString.  I'd like to keep it clean with line returns like

```
SELECT * FROM table as t
JOIN location as loc 
on t.position = loc.value
```

Is there a way to wrap a long SQL statement (the actual statement is much longer) in an NSString with line breaks?  I'd rather not create a NSMutableString, and then appendFormat:.  Thanks.

Comment: You want the query to be readable in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSString *statement =
    @"line1\n"
     "line2\n"
     "line3\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM table as t \
                    JOIN location as loc \
                    on t.position = loc.value";
```